# How to install FitNesse on application server as war/ear

Tags: war, ear, fitnesse, application-server

Fitnesse [download page](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesseDownload) only has option for *standalone.jar* and this is also what the instructions are for. **Is it somehow possible to install FitNesse on a separate app server, such as Tomcat**? There's not directly any war/ear to download, but can I bundle one somehow?

I'm experimenting with acceptance testing frameworks and **need to run the tests on a very specific test environment**, and thus require a possibility for installing on an already running app container where the tests are executed. Changes for getting even java executable from command line in this environment are slim, and if possible, the process would take probably months to realize.

Comment: Found a [post](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/fitnesse/conversations/topics/21047) where someone else is apparently also struggling with similar requirements. Based on the reply there, FitNesse does not support such functionality by default.

Comment: Even if you were to get the wiki running inside an app server, a test run would still try to start a new java process (by starting the java executable) so you still need access to that executable. But does the test environment really need to be in the app server? I usually use FitNesse to test an application from the outside: the test framework makes remote (http) calls to an application running in an app server, but it does not run in that same app server itself.

Comment: @Fried Good points. FitNesse does not necessarily need to be on the same server as the app under test, but as there are firewalls etc part of the picture, using another server for this purpose might be problematic. I'll have to check the option. Anyway, I think you have answered the question (It's no possible to have FitNesse as Ear/War and furthermore does not help at all), so please copy your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible, but even if you were to get the wiki running inside an app server, a test run would still try to start a new java process (by starting the java executable) so you still need access to that executable.

But does the test environment really need to be in the app server? I usually use FitNesse to test an application from the outside: the test framework makes remote (http) calls to an application running in an app server, but it does not run in that same app server itself.